# Hadoop filesystem with kerberose

Tags: hadoop, filesystems, webhdfs

I am new to hadoop filesystem. I didn't find any helpful link on google related to Hadoop FileSystem.

I want to authenticate using Kerberose while using Hadoop FileSystem.

Sample Code :

```
    Path src = new Path("C:\\testing\\a\\a.avro");
    Path dest = new Path("webhdfs://aaaa:50070/dummy/dummy.avro");
    WebHdfsFileSystem web = new WebHdfsFileSystem();
    try {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        conf.set("fs.default.name","webhdfs://aaaa:50070");
        web.setConf(conf);
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(web.getConf());
        fs.copyFromLocalFile(false,src,dest);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

How do i achieve kerberos authication with the above code? How to set principle and keytab values?

Comment: Okay, what's ... the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer to your question is: your hdfs-client code knows how to authenticate if you configure everything right (absolutely nothing to do with the code you posted here).

I recommend you go over the Hadoop security tutorials.

- [Configure Secure Hadoop](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP1/HDP-1.3.0/bk_installing_manually_book/content/rpm-chap14-2-3-1.html) (Hadoop 1.3 Hortonworks)
- [Adding Security Information to Configuration Files](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.0.9.1/bk_installing_manually_book/content/rpm-chap14-2-3.html) (Hadoop 2.0 Hortonworks)
- [Configuring Hadoop Security in CDH4](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH4/4.6.0/CDH4-Security-Guide/cdh4sg_topic_3_7.html)
- [Configuring Hadoop Security in CDH 5](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH5/latest/CDH5-Security-Guide/cdh5sg_cdh5_hadoop_security.html)

It seems that your hdfs-client is a Windows system. To access a Kerberized cluster (including Kerberized HDFS) you'll need to enable TGT session access, see [Registry Key to Allow Session Keys to Be Sent in Kerberos Ticket-Granting-Ticket](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308339) and you have to make sure your process is not an UAC restricted administrator (see [Access to Session Keys not possible using a restricted Token](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2627903)).

Your cluster cannot be a Windows cluster, Kerberized Windows clusters are still in development ([YARN-1063](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/YARN-1063), [YARN-1972](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/YARN-1972) etc).